# Getting data from GSON parsor to Camel Spring

Tags: java, spring, gson, apache-camel

I am using Spring DSL to get JSON formatted data to Camel.
I wrote the code like this,

```
<bean id="mqtt" class="org.apache.camel.component.mqtt.MQTTComponent"/>
    <bean id="gson" class="org.apache.camel.component.gson.GsonDataFormat"/>
    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="mqtt:bar?host=tcp://10.30.11.0:1883&amp;subscribeTopicName=apss/messages" />
            <unmarshal ref="gson" />
            <camel:choice>
                <camel:when>
                    <!-- I dont knwo what to write here -->
                    <camel:to uri="stream:out" />
                </camel:when>
                <camel:otherwise>
                    <camel:to uri="stream:out" />
                </camel:otherwise>
            </camel:choice>
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

I want to compare the first field with a string and decide to do what after parsing.
I know that GSON will parse the JSON string to a hashmap. So I want to do a get(0) with the hashmap.
But I don't know how to do it in spring. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.
I am putting it for others.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="mqtt:apsssub?host=tcp://10.30.11.0:1883&amp;subscribeTopicName=apss/messages" />
            <unmarshal ref="gson" />
            <bean beanType="com.hk.MessageHeaderSetter" method="putMessageTypeInHeader" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${headers.msg_type} == 'location_update'</simple>
                    <log message="Message type 1." />
                    <to uri="jms:LOCATION_UPDATE_QUEUE" />method="updateLocation" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log message="Other message" />
                    <log message="Headers ${headers}" />
                    <to uri="stream:out" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Here putMessageTypeInHeader in MessageHeaderSetter will explicitly put the message type in header.

```
public void putMessageTypeInHeader(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("msg_type", ((HashMap)exchange.getIn().getBody()).get("msg_type"));
}
```

I don't know why people not responding to my question!!